# Subtraction between cross columns

Tags: sql, teradata, common-table-expression

```
Year_1  Product CDpasshr    PCWHr
201801  TANF Standard   22.205  0
201801  TANF Standard   0   22
```

Expected O/P

```
201801  TANF Standard   22.205  22
```

Comment: What happens if there be more than two records in a group?  What would the subtraction logic be then?

Comment: The answer to your question is NO Its always two  Thanks

Comment: I think if you send more sample data, it will be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output implies you want the following query:

```
SELECT
    Year_1,
    Product,
    MAX(CDpasshr) - MIN(CDpasshr) AS CDpasshr,
    MAX(PCWHr) - MIN(PCWHr) AS PCWHr
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Year_1,
    Product;
```

It seems that you want to report the absolute difference between the two rows in each group, for the `CDpasshr` and `PCWHr` columns.  Taking the difference of the max and min should work, since this difference should always be positive.  Note that my answer assumes that a given group would always contain two records.  If not, then the answer would have to be changed.

Comment: I tend to think this is the correct answer, though there a few points I can't really see well.